# User-private connection between my Google Chrome extension and my native program on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome-extension, p2p

I have a 'native' program (in Java) which would like to communicate with a Google Chrome/Chromium extension. The communication contains sensitive informations, and should not be accessible by anybody else than the user running them (and the root of course).

What technology should I choose for this communication channel? Is there even a solution?

**EDIT:**
Of course I could open a TCP/IP port on the local host, but wouldn't it be accessible by other users having an account on the same host? Is there a technic to avoid that side effect?

Could we access unix domain sockets from Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: Note for p2p enthusiasts: I need this communication channel between a browser and the local node of my p2p application. They should both run on the same host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I chose is to have an server socket listening on the loopback interface (/ 127.0.0.1) with a shared secret used as an api key.

The reason is that I didn't realize that in my case each app which connect to my node had to be **authenticated** .. because each app is treated in a different way, with different access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already familiar with TCP, if you use localhost / 127.0.0.1 for the communication it would not be visible/available for other machines.

Comment: True, but the problem is that users from other accounts on the same host can still connect. I might use this for my prototype, but that's not a final solution.

Comment: On unix platforms you could probably use unix domain sockets which would allow you to figure out who is connecting, but whether this is supported by java or not I have no idea. You could build your own authentication on top of any protocol of course, but that may be overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MariusKjeldahl moreover, the other users can't run the program while you are running it.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this at the higher level with a secured SSL communication with certificates etc... IF someone does not have the certificate, then the connection is killed. Moreover, you would benefit from encryption.

Comment: If I go for the encryption rather than the isolation, I would need to authenticate the connecting Chrome extension, and I'd prefer not having to authenticate for communications between programs ran by the same user account. The reason is to make the installation/setup process easier for the user.

Comment: How are you going to achieve the level of security you are looking for with 'isolation'? In order to achieve isolation, you need control, and an average unix user never reaches the level of unix control on connection to meet your requirements. And there no guarantee that this would we watertight too. P2P won't solve your issue, unless you use secured communications on top of it too. But then, why use P2P in the 1st place...

Comment: I am thinking about Unix Domain Sockets .. i.e. file-system-based sockets. By isolation I mean via the access rights within 1 unix-based host. I am already using encryption between nodes of my f2f network.

Comment: PS: If you could tag this question with 'f2f' instead of 'p2p', that would be helpful. I can't do it myself because the 'f2f' tag doesn't exist yet and I don't have enough reputation to create it.